# Google Maps specific part

Tags: google-maps

I am working on Google maps V3 and i want to get a specific part of Google map like i want to display only Pakistan on Google map and other map should hide completely .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can't hide other map parts completely but you can set boundaries to the map so that the user cannot scroll any further than the defined point

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'center_changed',function() { checkBounds(); });

function checkBounds() {    
if(! allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
  var C = map.getCenter();
  var X = C.lng();
  var Y = C.lat();

  var AmaxX = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lng();
  var AmaxY = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lat();
  var AminX = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lng();
  var AminY = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

  if (X < AminX) {X = AminX;}
  if (X > AmaxX) {X = AmaxX;}
  if (Y < AminY) {Y = AminY;}
  if (Y > AmaxY) {Y = AmaxY;}

  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(Y,X));
}
}
```